# Which spaces satisfy the statement of perfect normality for $3$ or more sets?

Tags: general-topology

If $A_0, A_1\subseteq X$ are disjoint closed sets and $X$ is perfectly normal, then there is continuous $f:X\to [0, 1]$ such that $A_0 = f^{-1}(0), A_1 = f^{-1}(1)$.

In general if $A_0, ..., A_n$ are disjoint closed, then there doesn't have to exist $f:X\to [0, 1]$ with $A_i = f^{-1}(\frac{i}{n})$, since $X = S^1$ is a counter-example.

Is there a simple description of spaces such that for any disjoint closed $A_0, ..., A_n$ with $n\leq m$ there is continuous $f:X\to [0, 1]$ with $A_i = f^{-1}(\frac{i}{n})$? Here $m\in\mathbb{N}$ is a fixed constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $m\geq 2$, your condition is equivalent to $X$ being perfectly normal and *ultranormal*, i.e. any two disjoint closed sets can be separated by clopen sets.  In the forward direction, just note that if $A,B\subseteq X$ are disjoint closed sets, then your condition with $n=2$ says that there exists $f:X\to [0,1]$ that sends $A$ to $0$, $B$ to $0$, and does not take the value $1/2$, and then $f^{-1}([0,1/2))$ and $f^{-1}((1/2,1])$ are clopen sets separating $A$ and $B$.  In the reverse direction, suppose $X$ is perfectly normal and ultranormal, and let $A_0,\dots,A_n\in X$ be disjoint closed sets.  By an easy induction on $n$, we can partition $X$ into clopen subsets such that each $A_i$ is contained in one of the clopen subsets.  Then by perfect normality, you can map each of the clopen sets to $[0,1]$ such that only the $A_i$ map to $i/n$.

(You might try to get a less trivial answer by requiring the $A_i$ to be nonempty, but I think this is artificial and doesn't give you anything interesting.  In particular, for instance, your condition for $m=2$ still implies strong disconnectedness properties, since if $A,B\subseteq X$ are disjoint closed sets which are contained in a connected proper subset $Y\subset X$, you could take $A_0=A, A_2=B$, and $A_1$ to be a point of $X\setminus Y$.  So as long as $X$ is $T_1$, this would imply that no connected proper subset of $X$ can contain more than one point.)